# Follow Button issue

Tags: facebook, button

I installed Follow Button for Facebook Brand Page ORANGE UND PINK here: http://www.orangeundpink.de in the Footer, but if I try to use it, I always get the Error message: "Unable to Subscribe: We were unable to create this subscription."

I put all snippets in the code as requested, The Button appear but after I push it, I get error.
Please help me with this issue if possible.
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "follow" button is meant to be used for personal accounts, e.g. to follow status updates of a user on Facebook.  What I think you are looking for is the "Like" button, which is meant to allow people to show their interest in a page, which is what your site on Facebook is.  An example of some code for a "like" button (from [Facebook's like button generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)):

```
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Orange-und-Pink-Studio/133559923520998" data-width="450" data-colorscheme="dark" data-show-faces="true" data-send="false"></div>
</body>
```